# How to debug slow boot on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi, secure-boot, logo

Since the installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo Flex2 Pro 15, the time between pressing the power button and the appearance of the LENOVO logo on screen is unusually long, i.e. more than 30 seconds. The screen is completely black during this time.

Once the LENOVO logo is finally displayed, the Ubuntu logo follows shortly after and the boot sequence proceeds as expected. Not extremely fast, but ok.

This was not the case when I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed (which did not display the LENOVO logo at boot), so I'm suspecting the new logo-feature could be related to this issue.

I do have SecureBoot enabled, but I'm not sure if that's related. What I do remember is that I had SecureBoot enabled on 18.04 as well, but as said I did not have the issue of slow booting.

Also, when I hit any key (other than F2/Setup or F12/Boot menu) during the time that the screen is black, the screen remains black indefinitely and the system seems to hang.

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
5.177s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
4.186s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
3.374s dev-sda2.device                                                                          
2.362s dev-loop10.device                                                                        
2.317s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
2.231s dev-loop9.device                                                                         
2.227s snapd.service                                                                            
2.216s dev-loop11.device                                                                        
2.146s dev-loop14.device                                                                        
2.111s dev-loop15.device                                                                        
2.103s dev-loop13.device                                                                        
2.074s dev-loop16.device                                                                        
2.059s dev-loop12.device                                                                        
2.047s dev-loop18.device                                                                        
2.036s dev-loop17.device                                                                        
2.033s dev-loop19.device                                                                        
2.028s dev-loop20.device                                                                        
1.916s postfix@-.service                                                                        
1.871s dev-loop3.device                                                                         
1.862s dev-loop2.device                                                                         
1.858s dev-loop23.device                                                                        
1.841s dev-loop25.device                                                                        
1.826s dev-loop21.device                                                                        
1.811s dev-loop26.device                                                                        
1.807s dev-loop24.device                                                                        
1.798s dev-loop22.device                                                                        
1.765s dev-loop4.device                                                                         
1.735s dev-loop5.device                                                                         
1.723s dev-loop27.device                                                                        
1.699s dev-loop1.device                                                                         
1.677s dev-loop0.device                                                                         
1.672s dev-loop7.device                                                                         
1.649s dev-loop29.device                                                                        
1.611s dev-loop6.device                                                                         
1.602s dev-loop31.device                                                                        
1.597s dev-loop28.device                                                                        
1.585s dev-loop30.device                                                                        
1.350s systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
1.255s snap-speedy\x2dduplicate\x2dfinder-22.mount                                              
1.254s snap-speedy\x2dduplicate\x2dfinder-27.mount                                              
1.217s snap-snapd-8790.mount                                                                    
1.194s snap-warzone2100-1573.mount                                                              
1.156s snap-scrcpy-238.mount                                                                    
1.071s snap-warzone2100\x2dvideos-2.mount                                                       
1.067s snap-keepassxc-1006.mount                                                                
1.064s systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
1.052s snap-obs\x2dstudio-1090.mount                                                            
1.044s snap-scrcpy-243.mount                                                                    
1.032s snap-snapd-8542.mount                                                                    
1.010s snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount                                                             
 986ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
 972ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                                   
 875ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount                                                   
 863ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount                                           
 847ms snap-signal\x2ddesktop-326.mount                                                         
 809ms snap-sweethome3d\x2dhomedesign-9.mount                                                   
 747ms snap-keepassxc-978.mount                                                                 
 746ms snap-minetest-1521.mount                                                                 
 657ms snap-minetest-1619.mount                                                                 
 628ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount                                                             
 621ms udisks2.service                                                                          
 597ms snap-core18-1880.mount                                                                   
 595ms snap-obs\x2dstudio-1118.mount                                                            
 585ms snap-signal\x2ddesktop-327.mount                                                         
 564ms snap-core-9665.mount                                                                     
 559ms wg-quick@wg0-client.service                                                              
 555ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                                  
 550ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount                                                     
 544ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dcommunity-249.mount                                             
 511ms snap-core-9804.mount                                                                     
 473ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount                                                  
 466ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
 455ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
 446ms plymouth-read-write.service                                                              
 417ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dcommunity-246.mount                                             
 372ms snap-core18-1885.mount                                                                   
 332ms upower.service                                                                           
 326ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
 287ms snap-gimp-281.mount                                                                      
 287ms snap-gimp-292.mount                                                                      
 280ms snapper-boot.service                                                                     
 277ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
 276ms fwupd.service                                                                            
 259ms avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
 252ms bluetooth.service                                                                        
 224ms apport.service                                                                           
 223ms polkit.service                                                                           
 215ms motd-news.service                                                                        
 207ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
 197ms ModemManager.service                                                                     
 195ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
 193ms switcheroo-control.service                                                               
 185ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                                   
 184ms plymouth-start.service                                                                   
 180ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
 179ms thermald.service                                                                         
 176ms grub-common.service                                                                      
 168ms gpu-manager.service                                                                      
 165ms rsyslog.service                                                                          
 162ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
 160ms user@1000.service                                                                        
 158ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
 154ms secureboot-db.service                                                                    
 150ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
 147ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
 123ms colord.service                                                                           
 120ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 
 110ms apparmor.service                                                                         
 109ms systemd-random-seed.service                                                              
 109ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
 102ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-EBBB\x2d0E8C.service                                    
  98ms home.mount                                                                               
  96ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
  91ms teamviewerd.service                                                                      
  82ms snapd.seeded.service                                                                     
  77ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       
  77ms gdm.service                                                                              
  55ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                              
  53ms pppd-dns.service                                                                         
  47ms kerneloops.service                                                                       
  46ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
  44ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
  43ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-139a2ef0\x2d2474\x2d484d\x2dbde8\x2d192ade6e4696.service
  36ms openvpn.service                                                                          
  33ms run-rpc_pipefs.mount                                                                     
  29ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
  28ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                            
  27ms rpcbind.service                                                                          
  26ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                                               
  23ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
  22ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                                            
  22ms modprobe@drm.service                                                                     
  20ms boot-efi.mount                                                                           
  19ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                                      
  19ms setvtrgb.service                                                                         
  18ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                                         
  16ms ufw.service                                                                              
  16ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                   
  15ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                                 
  14ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                                     
  12ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                                      
  11ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                
  10ms console-setup.service                                                                    
   9ms nfs-config.service                                                                       
   5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                                            
   3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                                  
   3ms swapfile.swap                                                                            
   2ms postfix.service                                                                          
   1ms snapd.socket
```

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @10.836s
└─multi-user.target @10.836s
  └─postfix.service @10.833s +2ms
    └─postfix@-.service @8.915s +1.916s
      └─network-online.target @8.912s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.724s +4.186s
          └─NetworkManager.service @4.396s +326ms
            └─dbus.service @4.385s
              └─basic.target @4.362s
                └─sockets.target @4.362s
                  └─snapd.socket @4.361s +1ms
                    └─sysinit.target @4.357s
                      └─snapd.apparmor.service @4.006s +207ms
                        └─apparmor.service @3.894s +110ms
                          └─local-fs.target @3.892s
                            └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @5.516s
                              └─run-snapd-ns.mount @5.048s
                                └─local-fs-pre.target @638ms
                                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @560ms +77ms
                                    └─systemd-sysusers.service @438ms +120ms
                                      └─systemd-remount-fs.service @406ms +26ms
                                        └─systemd-journald.socket @390ms
                                          └─system.slice @382ms
                                            └─-.slice @382ms
```

Comment: Start with `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Add those outputs to your Question above.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Ubuntu part of the boot process: 10.8 seconds is fantastic. While there might be delay with BIOS or loading the Kernel, those will be a much greater challenge to investigate...so I'll bow out.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks anyway! Just what has changed between 18.04 and 20.04 that could be causing this?

Comment: Difficult to say. None of my Ubuntu hardware platforms, nor my test environments have shown a significantly longer boot. The Ubuntu developers didn't say "*hey boot is too short -- let's stretch it out*." Indeed, they would love to know about this issue...once they know how to duplicate it on their systems so they can troubleshoot it. Most "*my boot is too long*" threads are a misconfiguration...but apparently not yours.

Comment: One thing I've noticed now, when I booted KDE Neon from a USB stick (just to try it out), is that the initial KDE Neon boot menu did not show. The screen remained black. Only when I hit 'Enter', did the live environment boot (without problems). So... Could it be that GRUB or whatever pre-boot environment is used, simply is not displayed? If that's the case, it would explain why the system remains in the 'black screen' state when I hit keys like C, Shift, ESC etc. because it would cancel the countdown.